# Write "chapter" before list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, naming, thmtools

if I use the `\listoffigures` command LaTeX creates a new chapter (I'm using the book class), but there is no chapter heading. Is it like it uses `\chapter*{List of figures}`. Of course this is what we want most of the cases, but what can I do to obtain a:

```
Chapter 3
List of figures
```

Actually I need these for the command `\listoftheorems` from the `thmtools` package, but it should be the same.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I see, ok! It seems to me a little exaggerated to delete my "thank you", but no problems!

Comment: Do you need this only for the lost of theorems and not for the other lists (of figures, of tables,...)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `\listoftheorems` uses internally `\listoffigures`, you can use the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch `\listoffigures` changing the default `\chapter*` to `\chapter` (for a solution using `amsbook`, please see the second example below):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theo}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{}{}
\listoftheorems
\clearpage
\begin{theo}[a]
Test theorem
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}[b]
Test theorem
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}[c]
Test theorem
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}[d]
Test theorem
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar patch can be easily done for other lists if required. For example, for the list of tables, one would say

```
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{}{}
```

A request has been made to perform a similar modification but using `amsbook`; in this case, some additional work has to be done:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theo}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}{\@makeschapterhead}{\@makechapterhead}{}{}
\def\@dotsep{1000}
\def\listoftheorems{\refstepcounter{chapter}\@starttoc{loe}\listtheoremname}
\def\l@figure{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{}{}}
\makeatother
\listoftheorems

\clearpage

\begin{theo}[a]
Test theorem
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}[b]
Test theorem
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}[c]
Test theorem
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}[d]
Test theorem
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I've got to start using `\patchcmd`!

Comment: It is this possible to do the same with amsbook?

Comment: @user29372 No; using `amsbook` requires some additional work. Please see the second example code in my udpated answer. Please *always* mention in your questions which document class you are using. As you now know that information is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are expecting the following behaviour:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }

\makeatother

\chapter{AA}

\begin{figure}
\caption{aa}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}
\caption{baa}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\caption{caa}
\end{figure}


\listoffigures

\end{document}
```