# List of figures as chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

I want my list of figures look like an ordinary chapter in my appendix. But right now my table of contents looks like this: [image]

This is how I add my list of figures:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
```

Apparently `\listoffigures` uses `\chapter*` instead of `\chapter`. Basically I want the numbering to look like this:

```
Appendix
A. List of Figures
B. Appendix test chapter 1
C. Appendix test chapter 2
```

I tried using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109802/write-chapter-before-list-of-figures) but it had no effect.

```
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{}{}
```

Is it possible to do it like this? Is there a better way?

Edit: I just came up with the following hack:

```
\renewcommand\listfigurename{A. List of Figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
```

This fixes my table of contents but unfortunately the pdf bookmark for my list of figures is now name "A. List of Figures" as well but I want it to be simply "List of Figures".

Edit2 with MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\part{Appendix}

\appendix
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Appendix chapter 1}
\chapter{Appendix chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you at least tell what class you're using? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be even better.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. I just started using Latex and I'm still a bit overwhelmed by all the features/classes ;)
See my 2nd edit for an MWE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `scrreprt` class already has the relevant feature:

```
\documentclass[listof=numbered]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\appendix

\listoffigures

\chapter{Appendix chapter 1}
\chapter{Appendix chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

Add `\cleardoublepage` before changing the page numbering style (but the appendix with Roman page numbers is very unusual).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I know the numbering style is unusual but it's required...

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way to solve your problem...

```
\begingroup
\chapter{\label{table_index}List of Figures}
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
\listoftables
\endgroup
```

hf :)

Comment: This does not answer the question... Redefining `\chapter` would only remove the chapter setting, but not display that includes an adjusted numbering scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my first edit I managed to fix my pdf bookmark problem using `\texorpdfstring`.

```
\renewcommand\listfigurename{A. List of Figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}}
\listoffigures
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
```

Everything works now but I would still be interested in a prettier solution.