# List of figures as a chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

I am trying to generate a list of figures and tables. As they form part of the final part of my thesis, I want them as a chapter. Bibliography is A, Appendix is B and so on... I manage to delete the title of the "List of figures", but when I want to include it in the chapter, it does not work. The chapter "list of figures" is empty and one page later, the list of figures appears without title.

```
\chapter[List of figures]
\renewcommand\listfigurename{}
\listoffigures
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\textbf{List of figures}}
```

I have also tried to put the title of lof as C. List of figures and remove it as a chapter. That's a solution, but not very elegant, as up to that part, all the chapters below will have to be entered manually. Does anybody have a better alternative?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it. The etoolbox did not work for me. Thanks, though.

What it did was to change the documentclass to scrreprt and include listof=numbered while defining the documentclass.
I also joined lof with lot.

```
\listoffigures
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\endgroup
```

Solutions were here: [List of figures as chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164675/list-of-figures-as-chapter) (even though I had to test some alternatives)
and for binding lof with tol: [How to show \listoffigures and \listoftables on one page and in the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14510/how-to-show-listoffigures-and-listoftables-on-one-page-and-in-the-toc)

Comment: You should have specified that you wanted a KOMA solution instead of a LaTeX solution.  The two have little in common.